# Determine accuracy of model on train data with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, prediction, accuracy

I am trying to compare the accuracy of my XGBoost model output to that of a test set (data encoded in binary). My data is stored in a Pandas DataFrame. I am doing this with SKLearn by:

```
accuracy = accuracy_score(testData,predictions)
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Can't handle mix of multilabel-indicator and binary
```

I am getting this despite both DataFrames containing the same columns and datatypes. I am not sure what to do next. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Upon inspection, it seems that my predictions DataFrame is instead a Numpy array. I believe this may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the original `accuracy_score()` function takes two arguments. First, is your test data labels (actual labels). Second, it takes your model's predictions.

```
 >>> accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
 >>> type(y_test)
 >>> <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
 >>> type(predicions)
 >>> <type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the test data to accuracy score? Accuracy score takes the validation labels and predicted labels as parameters.

I am assuming that test data is you validation set, result of your test data will be passed to the accuracy score.

```
/*y_true holds values of testData target variable,
y_pred holds the prediction values */

accuracy=accuracy_score(y_true.values,y_pred.values)
```

If y_true and y_preds are pandas series type then ".values" to convert them into list, so format of both arguments will be consistent.